# Login Failed with Existing User on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I just started playing around with PostgreSQL. My goal is to create a new user outside of postgres with all of the same privileges and create a database for my ror app. I'm able to login under postgres. I did create an user named `Jason`, which is good, however when I do `sudo -u username psql` I receive the following error...

```
sudo: unknown user: Jason
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I can determine that the username exists by checking both \dg in my postgres console.

```
                         List of roles
Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
Jason     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

What's causing this problem? Also, I checked my local `pg_hba.conf` and have what I believe to be the correct settings.

```
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are confusing *system user* with *database user*. The error message comes from `sudo` and has nothing to do with PostgreSQL at all.

To log in as database user Jason:

```
psql -U Jason
```

You need to supply a password, of course, as long as password-less access is not set up.  *Peer authentication* only works for a system user of the same name ("Jason").
More in the excellent manual about `psql` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and about authentication methods [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html).

Comment: Now I'm receiving this error... `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "Jason"`

Comment: I was able to login, but now I need to change the password for Jason since it doesn't work. Thanks for the help and the correct answer!

Comment: @jason328: Cool. I added pointers to the manual about psql & authentication.