# POSTGRES: FATAL: role "USERNAME" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Really struggling to get Postgres set up. I have installed it with home-brew (version 14). and installed the Postgres app through the website.

when I type the command 'psql' into my terminal it gives this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "edac" does not exist
```

my server is running on port 5432.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard installation of Postgres has `peer` authentication enabled in `pg_hba.conf`. If you start `psql` without parameters it looks to connect with a DB role of the same name as the current OS user - obviously "edac" in your case.

Either you create such a role in the database (and grant desired privileges to it), or you connect with a different (existing) role. In a fresh installation, at least the database role "postgres" exists, which is a superuser.

Either you log in with username and password. Or simpler, connect as OS user "postgres" to allow peer authentication with the DB role of the same name. Like:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Then you may want to create a DB role named "edac" (without superuser privileges):

```
CREATE ROLE edac;
```

Or, to just do that in one step with the shell command [createuser](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html):

```
sudo -u postgres createuser edac
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist)
- [Login Failed with Existing User on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004297/login-failed-with-existing-user-on-postgresql/13004400#13004400)

Comment: I get error `unknown user postgres` ... I actually the `"/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "mycurrentusername" does not exist` for any command for example `psql postgres`

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL v14+ installed via Brew on Mac OS Monterey on Intel Silicon, the following steps solved it for me:

1. Navigate to /usr/local/opt/**postgres@14**/bin

*-NOTE: The above path is different from a lot of older answers as it seems older versions of PostgreSQL didn't use the version number in the directory name.*

2. `createuser -U postgres -s ${USER}`
3. Try `psql postgres` again.